# Use class name for conditional macro expansion

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function **A** whose code changes a bit depending on if the input is a struct **B** or a struct **C**. I don't want to write **A** twice, so I encapsulated the difference in the `()` operator of the structs.

My problem is that **A** processes a lot of data, and the `()` operator is called extensively. I would like to replace that part with macros to improve the performance of my code. Something like this:

```
#define B_TASK(data) //macro for B's task
#define C_TASK(data) //macro for C's task

struct B();
struct C();

template<class struct_t>
function A(struct_t data){
     //some irrelevant code
     .
     .
     while(..){ //extensive loop
         #if data == B //my original code uses data()
            B_TASK(data)
         #else
            C_TASK(data)
         #endif
     }
}

int main(){
    B b_inst;
    C c_inst;

    A<B>(b_inst);
    A<C>(c_inst);
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this? I don't know how to ask for the struct name in the preprocessor `#if`.

Comment: `if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<struct_t, B> )` might help

Comment: imho lazyness is a good motivation, but when you think you need macros you went a bit too far. The function is already a template, why add macros on top of that?

Comment: MACRO should mostly be the last resort solution. And MACRO is not the solution here.

Comment: Yes, MACRO es my last option. The A function processes a huge string stream (semi-external) with millions of characters. Every time a substring in the string meets some property, then the () operation is called.  Thus, () is called a million times.  In simple terms, I am using MACROS beacuse the size of the problem is too big.

Comment: The preprocessor happens before any instantiations of templates, therefore, it occurs too early in the process to be able to do what you want.

Comment: frankly, how often you call it or how long the string is you pass to `()` or the size of the problem is irrelevant. Macros dont bring any advantage here

Answer (score 2):

This is possible if C++17's [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) and the [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) type trait.  That would look like

```
template<class struct_t>
function A(struct_t data){
     //some irrelevant code
     while(...){ //extensive loop
         if constexpr(std::is_same_v<struct_t, B>)
            B_TASK(data)
         if constexpr(std::is_same_v<struct_t, C>)
            C_TASK(data)
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!, I wasn't aware of the constexpif statement, very useful!!. Unfortunately, I am using C++11's :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use `constexpr if` (C++17) or you can refactor your code into (is fine already pre C++11):

```
struct B{};
struct C{};


void task(const B& b) {
     // implementation for B's task
}
void task(const C& c) {
     // implementation for C's task
}

template<class struct_t>
void A(struct_t data){
     // code is never irrelevant, comments are
     while(true) { 
         task(data);
         break;
     }
}

int main(){
    B b_inst;
    C c_inst;

    A<B>(b_inst);
    A<C>(c_inst);
}
```

I would never use macros for this situation. They have severe downsides and there is no need to resort to macros here.

**PS**

> ```
> #if data == B //my original code uses data()
> ```

As was already mentioned in a comment, there is no way to have the macro depending on the template parameter, because macros are expanded before templates are instantiated.

Comment: Thanks!!, my original code overloads the () operator in structs A and B. My real problem is that () operator is called too many times (the data I am processing is huge, several GBs). In such a scenario, replacing the () operator with a macro will improve computing time.

Comment: @AAA no it will not! I dont know what to do other than repeating myself. No! Using a macro will not magically improve performance! Macros do not exist at runtime, they do not even exist at the time the compiler actually starts to compile the code. Hence there is no way using a macro can have an effect on the performance at runtime

Comment: @AAA maybe you can open a different question which is more related to your real situation to clarify that. Discussing performance of your code without seeing it is difficult

Comment: I am aware a MACRO is just text replacement and does not DIRECTLY affect the performance of my code. I just want to avoid *calling* the operator () too many times because there is an overhead on that (considering the huge size of my input data). Of course, I can write A twice one for struct A and other for struct B, and the effect will be the same as those of the macro expansion. But rewriting A twice is exactly the thing I don't want to do.

Comment: @AAA `A` is a template, you do not have to write it twice. As I said, there is no `operator()` in your example, so it is not clear what you are talking about. If you think macros help with performance I think you should open another question to clarify that

Comment: Ok, I will ask again with more extensive code to make myself clear ;) Thanks!